# How to animate an image moving across the screen?

Tags: flutter

I have a fixed size image (of a playing card) and I'd like to write code so users see the image slide from one part of the screen to another (like a card being dealt and moving across the surface). If possible, it would be best to do so in a way that's moderately responsive for different screen sizes.

Most of what I've seen or learned about involves Hero widgets or animation where a widget changes size but stays in the same location. I'm asking about something different.

Comment: Like CSS animations? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: @Michael -- Yes, like the CSS animation in your link :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use Flutter's built in [animations](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial) `Animation<double>`. In Flutter, an Animation object knows nothing about what is onscreen. An Animation is an abstract class that understands its current value and its state (completed or dismissed). One of the more commonly used animation types is `Animation<double>`.

For example:

```dart
// lib/main.dart (AnimatedLogo)
class AnimatedLogo extends AnimatedWidget {
  AnimatedLogo({Key key, Animation<double> animation})
      : super(key: key, listenable: animation);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final animation = listenable as Animation<double>;
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        height: animation.value,
        width: animation.value,
        child: FlutterLogo(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or you can import and use one of these packages into your project:

- https://pub.dev/packages/simple_animations
- https://pub.dev/packages/animator

Comment: Starting with @aminrd's response, I also found https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/10/animation-apps-flutter/ to be really useful.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the animatedPosition widget, it will move any widget from one point of the screen to another, you can even morph the size of the widget.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html

```
AnimatedPositioned(
        width: selected ? 200.0 : 50.0,
        height: selected ? 50.0 : 200.0,
        top: selected ? 50.0 : 150.0,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              selected = !selected;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: const Center(child: Text('Tap me')),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```